# Restlet ServerResource method parameters with special characters

Tags: parameters, restlet, url-parameters, restlet-2.0

> .../address?street=2767 Pembroke St #979

When i get this url's parameter as

```
Form queryParams = getReference().getQueryAsForm();
String street = queryParams.getFirstValue("street");
```

I can't get with special character("**#**"). got as(2767 Pembroke St ).

How can we get parameter's values those contains "#" character?

Comment: Yes, encode the String with URL String encoder

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your URL. This link would help to provide the right content in your query string: http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php.

You should use: ../address?street=2767%20Pembroke%20St%20%23979

Hope it helps you,
Thierry